# Bootstrap btn scales will page, and I dont want it to

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I want to create an image with a popover, and this works just fine`<img src="images/Doc_icon.jpg" class="btn btn-lg" rel="popover" data-content="output" data-placement="right" data-trigger="click">`, except for one thing. The icon I'm using is acting responsively and shrinks with the page, how do I stop that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bootstrap by the default  All img tag have max-width: 100%

When you scale your browser,img try to scale too

Maybe this code can help you:

```
<img src="images/Doc_icon.jpg" class="btn btn-lg no-resize" rel="popover" data-   content="output" data-placement="right" data-trigger="click">

.no-resize{
    max-width: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set a fixed `with` and `height` for your image.

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer.